# how to save an image once certain condition accures in cam or video in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

hello i want to save an image if it meets certain condition in video capture
for example save an image if the person do the v sign for example how can i do that?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    tf, img = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #cv2.imwrite('v_sign.png',img) 
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if img == cv2.imread('v_sign.png'):
        cv2.imwrite('captured frame.png',img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: At a second read, it looks like you are trying to do a hand gesture recognition. There should be plenty google article on that topic.

Comment: thanks for answer but i get this error                     ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: `if (img == cv2.imread('v_sign.png')).all():`

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and likely-off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].